# Split PC audio between 6 Bluetooth headphones?

Tags: audio, playback

I'm looking to play a video presentation on a PC, and I'm trying to figure out a way to stream that presentation's audio across 6 Bluetooth headphones. Each headphone would have a USB dongle.

Is there a straightforward way of achieving this?

Comment: Please note that consumer audio questions are off-topic for sound.stackexchange, but in any case, unfortunately, the bluetooth protocol doesn't support this use case.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a consumer-related question; It seems like a specialist question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have researched this several months ago and I did not find a solution.

When you say "Each headphone would have a USB dongle." I assume that you mean that each headphone will have its own BlueTooth transmitter.  But the problem is getting some way to send the audio presentation out through several USB outputs concurrently.  There may be expensive commercial solutions, but that probably isn't what you are seeking.

In the professional production world, they use wireless earpieces and more traditional FM transmitter "broadcasting" where any number of earpiece receivers pick up the same "program".  This could be simulated with small inexpensive FM receivers and an FM transmitter.  All of these pieces are widely available online.

The major problem here is that BlueTooth was never designed as a "one-to-many" ("broadcasting") commmunication scheme. And there is no convenient way of sending audio to multiple BlueTooth channels (or out to multiple USB interfaces).

Comment: Thank you for the response Richard. Could you possibly point me in the direction of a transmitter, and wireless headphones that could receive that FM signal?

Comment: I went to Ebay and searched on "FM Radio" and "Buy Now" and sorted by price. I found at least a dozen different very small MP3 players/FM radios for less than $5.   You did not reveal what is the source of the audio, so it is more difficult to suggest any particular transmitter.  Are you playing from a PA mixer?, from an iPod?, from a phone? from a computer?

Comment: From a computer.

Comment: I searched on Ebay for "usb fm transmitter" and found this: http://www.ebay.com/itm/Wireless-audio-fm-transmitter-wireless-transmitter-receiver-headset-USB-sound-/321216361938  There are likely many other similar transmitters that would work for you.